# IBInspectable and default values in objective-c, black coloured view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibinspectable

I'm using IBInspectables in my objective-c project. I wan't to set some default value for these. It's not a simple as just setting a default value like you can in swift so I'm trying to do it in the init method like so:

```
@interface PushButtonView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor *fillColor;
@property IBInspectable BOOL isAddButton;

@end

@implementation PushButtonView

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){

        self.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.isAddButton = YES;

    }

    return  self;
}
```

This allows me to change the values in the interface builder as desired. However if I choose default as the fillColor for the button it is show as black in the interface builder and not blue. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the default color. As this color on a `UIButton` is Black. Your button will indeed appear black.

Comment: The default background colour for a view isn't the clear colour?